# SMARTY templating and variables

Tags: templates, variables, smarty

Ok, so I have something like this (and I can't use arrays - I know - UGH):

```
{assign var="ctaText1" value="Join Now"}
{assign var="ctaText2" value="News"}
{assign var="ctaText3" value="Photos"}
{assign var="ctaText4" value="Blog!"}
{assign var="ctaText5" value="Store"}

{math equation='rand(1,5)'}

<div>{$ctaText}</div>
```

Now, what I actually want is something like:

```
<div>{${$ctaText}{$equation}}</div>
```

Obviously, the above doesn't work - I've tried it and a few variations.  But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it so I get the correct random variable and pop in the text value for the DIV.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why you do this in your view?

Answer (score -1):

dirty as hell but it works:

```
{assign var="ctaText1" value="Join Now"}
{assign var="ctaText2" value="News"}
{assign var="ctaText3" value="Photos"}
{assign var="ctaText4" value="Blog!"}
{assign var="ctaText5" value="Store"}

{php}
    echo $this->get_template_vars('ctaText'.rand(1,5));
{/php}
```

You might think about refactoring the whole variable assignment